# Blob detection in grayscale images (skimage)

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I've used the scikit tutorial (http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_blob.html) to play with blob detection. I've changed the code to get only the difference of Gaussian

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage import data
from skimage.feature import blob_dog
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

image = data.imread('Img.png')

blobs_dog = blob_dog(image, max_sigma=30, threshold=.1)

blobs = [blobs_dog]
colors = ['red']
titles = ['Difference of Gaussian']
sequence = zip(blobs, colors, titles)

for blobs, color, title in sequence:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.imshow(image, interpolation='nearest')
    for blob in blobs:
        y, x, r = blob
        c = plt.Circle((x, y), r, color=color, linewidth=1, fill=False)
        ax.add_patch(c)

plt.show()
```

Now my question is: I used a grayscale image (I didn't modified it with the rgb2gray function), but when I run the code, as output I have a "colored" image (almost all cyan with some red and yellow spots). 
If I use a RGB image and then I transform it to grayscale I don't have problems. Why is it so?

Comment: By default, matplotlib uses a color map to display images. Try ``ax.imshow(image, interpolation='nearest', cmap='gray')``

Comment: It works, but it raise a RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arccos
  acos1 = arccos((d ** 2 + r1 ** 2 - r2 ** 2) / (2 * d * r1)). Do you know what does it mean?

Comment: Which code raises that warning?

Comment: The above one with the cmap = 'gray' added (and using the grayscale image as input). I had the same warning when I was trying to process the grayscale image even before (without the cmap parameter). And I'm using Pycharm (I've tried with Ipython notebook and I didn't have the warning).

Comment: I mean, do you have a source .py and line number for the raised warning?  I need to know exactly where the warning comes from.

Comment: yes, sorry, PyCharm indicates C:\Users\Me\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\skimage\feature\blob.py:55. I've noticed that this warning raises with some images and with some other don't (even if I use two different RGB pictures and I don't touch the code apart from the rgb2gray transformation).

Comment: That's useful, thanks!  Can you please file an issue on GitHub against 'scikit-image/scikit-image'?

Comment: Ok, now my code is slightly different, but I still have that warning. Do I have to post my file here https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image? Sorry for the (stupid) question, but since now I've only used GitHub to download lessons for my class.

Comment: Thank you for the issue you've filed on GitHub--we'll be sure to address the warning.